# Where exactly should the amud be placed?

Tags: halacha, minhag, tefilla, chazzan-prayer-leader, architecture-design

In some synagogues I have seen the amud (lectern) from where the chazan (prayer leader) stands to say the prayers, placed a few feet in front of the aron (cabinet) where the torah is kept or between the aron and the bima (reading table). In other synagogues I have also seen the amud placed a few feet to the right of the aron. Is there an exact location where the amud should be placed? Does it change location depending on its use? Where can I find this information for further study?

Comment: In fact, the amud or stender isn't required AFAIK and it is just wherever the shatz is standing. Any place that is valid for him to stand is valid for the podium.

Comment: the only thing i heard about positioning the *Amud*, is to put in on lower ground because it says in [Tehilim 130:1](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt26d0.htm#1) '**ממעמקים** קראתיך י-ה-ו-ה'

Comment: Can you refer some reading materials where I might read up on this topic?